# How can we print POS Receipt through Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

Here, requirement is to prepare receipt & print through Silverlight Application.I have to send raw data with POS commands like Partial Cut.It should support A8 size.Can it possible to communicate directly with POS or THERMAL Printer ?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight Out of Browser mode supports COM Automation. You will require at least Silverlight 4.

If your POS isn't callable by COM, then you will need to write the necessary COM wrappers.